# Counting Valleys - HackerRank Challenge

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, array

For [this challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup):

> A valley is a sequence of consecutive steps below sea level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step up to sea level.
>
> Given Gary's sequence of up and down steps during his last hike, find and print the number of valleys he walked through.
>
> For example, if Gary's path is s=[DDUUUUDD], he first enters a valley 2 units deep. Then he climbs out and up into a mountain 2 units high. Finally, he returns to sea level and ends the hike.

I reached a solution, but I'm sure it can be optimized:

```
function countingValleys(n, s) {
    let heightTracker = [];
    let height = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] === "D") {
            height--;
            heightTracker.push(height);
        }
        if (s[i] === "U") {
            height++;
            heightTracker.push(height);
        }
    }
    let planeTracker = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < heightTracker.length; j++) {
        if (heightTracker[j] < 0) {
            planeTracker.push("valley");
        }
        if (heightTracker[j] > 0) {
            planeTracker.push("mountain");
        }
        if (heightTracker[j] === 0) {
            planeTracker.push("flat");
        }
    }
    let newArray = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < planeTracker.length; k++) {
        if (planeTracker[k] === planeTracker[k - 1]) {
            continue;
        }
        if (planeTracker[k] !== planeTracker[k - 1]) {
            newArray.push(planeTracker[k]);
        }
    }
    let valleyCount = 0;
    for (let l = 0; l < newArray.length; l++) {
        if (newArray[l] === "valley") {
            valleyCount++;
        }
    }
    return valleyCount;
}
```

My logic was to keep track of all negative and positive values in `s`.

- If `heightTracker[j]` is negative, push "valley" into `planeTracker`
- If `heightTracker[j]` is positive, push "mountain" into `planeTracker`
- Otherwise, push "flat" into `planeTracker`

So at that point, I'm left with:

`[ 'valley', 'valley', 'valley', 'flat', 'valley', 'valley', 'valley', 'valley', 'valley', 'flat', 'mountain', 'flat' ]`

And I'm wondering, is there a way to filter out any elements that are the same as the element before them? The goal was to generate the array:

`[ 'valley', 'flat', 'valley', 'flat', 'mountain', 'flat']` and then count the number of times the word "valley" appears in that array. As you can see, I did this with a for-loop. But I'm wondering what other suggestions you'd have - maybe the `.filter()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're vastly overcomplicating the solution by introducing three arrays `heightTracker`, `planeTracker`, and `newArray`.  None of those is needed: just track the `elevation` (which is a better name than `height`), and go by the definition:

> A valley is a sequence of consecutive steps below sea level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step up to sea level.

So, the number of valleys traversed is the number of times Gary's elevation changes from -1 to 0.

```
function countingValleys(n, s) {
    let elevation = 0;
    let traversedValleys = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (s[i] === "D") {
            --elevation;
        } else if (s[i] === "U") {
            if (++elevation === 0) traversedValleys++;
        }
    }
    return traversedValleys;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, what is the difference between `--elevation` and `elevation--` or `++elevation` and `elevation++`?

Comment: See [Increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_%28%29).  `++elevation === 0` means to increment `elevation` _before_ comparing with 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found that instead of using the for-loop, I can use `filter()` like this:

```
planeTracker = planeTracker.filter((element, index, arr) => element !== arr[index + 1]);
```

To get rid of the elements that are the same as the previous element.

Comment: You shouldn't need `planeTracker` in the first place. But this is also poor style, since it ventures one element past the end of the array.

Comment: What if I switched it to `arr[index - 1]` - still bad practice? Ventures one element before the start of the array, correct?

Comment: Accessing before the beginning of the array feels even ickier.